# How to parse grammar `(a | b)* a`

Tags: python, parsing, grammar, pyparsing, bnf

Let's consider the grammar described by the following Backus-Naur form:

```
a ::= 'a'
b ::= 'b'
grammar ::= (a | b)* a
```

I'm trying to parse it using pyparsing and came to the following implementation

```
a = Literal('a')
b = Literal('b')
grammar = (a | b)[...] + 'a'
```

However, it fails to parse any of the string described by the grammar, with for example `grammar.parseString('aba')` raising

```
ParseException: Expected "a", found end of text  (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)
```

It seems to be caused by the fact that the `[...]` expression is parsed by consuming tokens until it is not possible to do it anymore. Then, there is no token left to be parsed by the last literal.

A way to do this would be to use the `FollowedBy` class:

```
grammar = ((a | b) + FollowedBy(a | b))[...] + a
```

which works. However it is highly inelegant, doesn't seem to be efficient, and is not really versatile.

Is there a better way to parse this grammar with pyparsing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are exactly right, pyparsing does not do backtracking like you might from a regex like `"[ab]*a"`. Pyparsing does no lookahead of any kind unless you explicitly implement it.

Here is an expanded version of your original parser, with added `setName` and `setDebug` calls:

```
a = Literal('a').setName("A").setDebug()
b = Literal('b').setName("B").setDebug()
grammar = (a | b)[...] + a().setName("trailing_a").setDebug()

grammar.runTests("""\
    aba
    """)
```

When parsing "aba", here is the debug output:

```
Match A at loc 0(1,1)
Matched A -> ['a']
Match A at loc 1(1,2)
Exception raised:Expected A, found 'b'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)
Match B at loc 1(1,2)
Matched B -> ['b']
Match A at loc 2(1,3)
Matched A -> ['a']
Match A at loc 3(1,4)
Exception raised:Expected A, found end of text  (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)
Match B at loc 3(1,4)
Exception raised:Expected B, found end of text  (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)
Match trailing_a at loc 3(1,4)
Exception raised:Expected trailing_a, found end of text  (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)

aba
   ^
FAIL: Expected trailing_a, found end of text  (at char 3), (line:1, col:4
```

and you can see the `trailing_a` getting matched as part of the initial repetition, not as a `trailing_a`. Since there is no actual trailing 'a' now, the parse fails.

You can either define a special form of `a` for the leading repetition (as you have done in one line) like this in two lines:

```
leading_a = a + FollowedBy(a | b)
grammar = (leading_a | b)[...] + 'a'
```

With debug output, we can follow the parser logic:

```
Match leading_a at loc 0(1,1)
Match A at loc 0(1,1)
Matched A -> ['a']
Match A at loc 1(1,2)
Exception raised:Expected A, found 'b'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)
Match B at loc 1(1,2)
Matched B -> ['b']
Matched leading_a -> ['a']
Match leading_a at loc 1(1,2)
Match A at loc 1(1,2)
Exception raised:Expected A, found 'b'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)
Exception raised:Expected A, found 'b'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)
Match B at loc 1(1,2)
Matched B -> ['b']
Match leading_a at loc 2(1,3)
Match A at loc 2(1,3)
Matched A -> ['a']
Match A at loc 3(1,4)
Exception raised:Expected A, found end of text  (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)
Match B at loc 3(1,4)
Exception raised:Expected B, found end of text  (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)
Exception raised:Expected {A | B}, found end of text  (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)
Match B at loc 2(1,3)
Exception raised:Expected B, found 'a'  (at char 2), (line:1, col:3)

aba
['a', 'b', 'a']
```

Or define a special `trailing_a`, and use the `stopOn` argument to `ZeroOrMore`:

```
trailing_a = a + ~FollowedBy(a | b)
grammar = OneOrMore(a | b, stopOn=trailing_a) + 'a'
```

to get similar results.

EDIT
Changing grammar to just `(a | b)[...]` shows this debugging output:

```
Match A at loc 0(1,1)
Matched A -> ['a']
Match A at loc 1(1,2)
Exception raised:Expected A, found 'b'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)
Match B at loc 1(1,2)
Matched B -> ['b']
Match A at loc 2(1,3)
Matched A -> ['a']
Match A at loc 3(1,4)
Exception raised:Expected A, found end of text  (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)
Match B at loc 3(1,4)
Exception raised:Expected B, found end of text  (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)

aba
['a', 'b', 'a']
```

So, yes, lookahead does incur a performance penalty.

pyparsing includes an internal cacheing capability, also known as "packrat parsing". Here is the debug output, with cached values marked with '*':

```
  Match trailing_a at loc 0(1,1)
  Match A at loc 0(1,1)
  Matched A -> ['a']
  Match A at loc 1(1,2)
  Exception raised:Expected A, found 'b'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)
  Match B at loc 1(1,2)
  Matched B -> ['b']
  Exception raised:Found unwanted token, FollowedBy:({A | B}), found 'b'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)
* Match A at loc 0(1,1)
* Matched A -> ['a']
  Match trailing_a at loc 1(1,2)
* Match A at loc 1(1,2)
* Exception raised:Expected A, found 'b'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)
* Exception raised:Expected A, found 'b'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)
* Match A at loc 1(1,2)
* Exception raised:Expected A, found 'b'  (at char 1), (line:1, col:2)
* Match B at loc 1(1,2)
* Matched B -> ['b']
  Match trailing_a at loc 2(1,3)
  Match A at loc 2(1,3)
* Matched A -> ['a']
  Match A at loc 3(1,4)
  Exception raised:Expected A, found end of text  (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)
  Match B at loc 3(1,4)
  Exception raised:Expected B, found end of text  (at char 3), (line:1, col:4)
  Matched trailing_a -> ['a']
* Match trailing_a at loc 2(1,3)
* Match A at loc 2(1,3)
* Matched A -> ['a']
* Matched trailing_a -> ['a']
```

Summary of "Match" operations:

- Without lookahead: 6
- With lookahead: 12
- With lookahead+packrat: 9

On a final note, it is possible to inject additional logic at parse time using parse actions. Parse actions can be written as a method (which can return a modified set of tokens, or raise an exception) or as a predicate function (which returns True or False, and pyparsing will raise an exception in the event of a False return).

So you could write your grammar using the fastest no-lookahead form, and then add a validating condition to be run afterward:

```
grammar = (a | b)[...]
grammar.addCondition(lambda t: t[-1] == 'a', message="string does not end with 'a'")
```

It is very likely that the savings in parse time would be enough to offset the added cost of doing the separate condition evaluation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Additionally, do you know how efficient both methods are, compared with parsing a simple `(a | b)*` grammar? In particular, is each of the tokens parsed twice, or can the results be cached? Does enabling packrat parsing have an effect here?